# Add a table alias retrieving relation using the with method Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would know if it's possible to give an alias to the table when you retrieve a relation using the `with` method with Eloquent ?

For exemple:

```
Post::where('title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')
    ->where('published', 1)
    ->with(['medias AS jpeg' => function($q) {
          $q->where('format', 'jpeg'); 
 }])->with(['medias AS gif' => function($q) {
          $q->where('format', 'gif');
 }])->first();
```

I know this doesn't work but it's in order to give you a situation.

Is it possible or do I have to this manually ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, since `with` doesn't accept tables, but relations names, and it stores the result for given relation just once.

So instead simply define different relations:

```
public function gifs()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Media')->where('format', 'gif');
}

public function jpegs()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Media')->where('format', 'jpeg');
}
```

`hasMany` or whatever relationship type it is obviously.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's easy.
But another question, for example, I have three tables calles international_content_fr, international_content_en and international_content_cn,
So I have three relation method so when I eagerLoad I would be able to pass a parameter to the relation method in order to have only one relation method for each international table.

Comment: No, you can't pass any params to the eager loading methods. Check polymorphic relations for this case.

Comment: In fact I could just modify a method within the Builder Class from laravel by testing if the value is not a closure, if not, pass the value as a parameter, easier, But you're solution is cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, you can always tweak the generic classes, however it's not the best way, not even good ;)